# Asking about a proof of a lemma in Pinter's A Book of Abstract Algebra Chapter 26 page 244

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm reading this proof:

> Lemma Let $a(x) = b(x)c(x)$, where $a(x), b(x)$, and $c(x)$ have integer coefficients. If a prime number p divides every coefficient of $a(x)$, it either divides every coefficient of $b(x)$ or every coefficient of $c(x)$.
>
> PROOF: If this is not the case, let $b_r$ be the first coefficient of $b(x)$ not divisible by $p$, and let $c_t$ be the first coefficient of $c(x)$ not divisible by $p$. Now, $a(x) = b(x) c(x)$, so
>
> $\qquad a_{r + t} = b_0c_{r + t} +\cdots+ b_rc_t + \cdots + b_{r + t}c_0$
>
> Each term on the right, except $b_rc_t$ is a product $b_ic_j$ where either $i > r$ or $j > t$. By our choice of $b_r$ and $c_t$, $\color{red}{\text{if }i > r\text{ then }p\,|\,b_i,\text{ and }j > t\text{ then }p\,|\,c_j}$. Thus, $p$ is a factor of every term on the right with the possible exception of $b_rc_n$ but $p$ is also a factor of $a_{r + t}$. Thus, $p$ must be a factor of $b_rc_n$ hence of either $b_r$ or $c_n$ and this is impossible.

Please first be noted that the text in red may give some confusion, but what he means by the first coefficient not divisible by $p$ is the first coefficient reading from the higher index. So e.g. if $5$ is the first coefficient then $..., 7, 6$ is divisible by $p$, but $5, 4, ...$ is not.

I could follow the proof well but the last sentence:

> Thus, $p$ must be a factor of $b_rc_n$ hence of either $b_r$ or $c_n$ and this is impossible.

I understand that $b_r c_n$ may not be divisible by $p$ because $b_r$ is the first coefficient not divisible by $p$. But how could it be that because $a_{r+t}$ is divisible by $p$ than $p$ must be the factor of either $b_r$ or $c_n$? Because e.g. if $10 = 7 + 3$, 10 is divisible by $5$, but certainly not for $7$ and $3$, so in this case $b_r c_n$ is not necessarily divisible by $p$.

And so certainly I also couldn't understand the last conclusion that "*this is impossible*".

Comment: The $n$'s in the last two sentences should be $t$'s.

Comment: They showed that p divides every term except one on the right and p also the left-hand number. So p divides the remaining term.

Comment: Aaahhh I seee it now... thanks thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your counter example is off base.  $7+3=10$ is divisible by $5$, but neither $7$ nor $3$ is.  In the quoted passage every term except one in a sum is divisible by $p$, as well as the sum itself.  Then we have a contradiction.